# How to display data read from a file using Electron and React?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, electron

My goal is simply to display data (using React) from a file stored locally with my Electron app. I've gotten halfway there in actually reading and processing the data, I just can't figure out *how to display it*.

Here's what I have for my file read:

```
export function read() {
  let values = [];

  fs.readFile(
    path.resolve(__dirname, './files/test.txt'),
    'utf-8',
    (err, data) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      values = data.toString().split('\n');

      const listItems = values.map(val => <p>{val}</p>);
      return listItems;
    }
  );
}
```

This works correctly, and I've console logged all the correct values.

The part that's confusing me is when I want to display it. Here's my react component:

```
// @flow
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styles from './ReadFile.css';
import { read } from '../actions/fileread';

type Props = {};

export default class ReadFile extends Component<Props> {
  props: Props;

  render() {
    const result = read();

    return (
      <div className={styles.container} data-tid="container">
        <p>Read from File</p>
        {result}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

What I would expect this to do is call the `read` function, store it in `result` and then print the results with `{result}`. What it does instead is display nothing. It also gives no errors.

I have a feeling this has to do with some odd server/client relationship between the react frontend and the node.js "backend" reading the file. I'm not sure how to create a simple interface between these two components to get them to work.

Comment: regardless of the communication between server/client your read function does not actually return anything. The code is asynchronous so you would need to return a promise or have a callback passed into read. Also this async code can't be called from within render() but you will want to use something like componentDidMount store it in state using setState and then reading it of state in your render.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment your code is async and your read() method is not returning anything. You should have something close to this:

```
export default class ReadFile extends Component<Props> {
  props: Props;
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    read((result) => {
      this.setState({
        result,
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={styles.container} data-tid="container">
        <p>Read from File</p>
        {this.state.result}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And for read() this:

```
export function read(callback) {
  let values = [];

  fs.readFile(
    path.resolve(__dirname, './files/test.txt'),
    'utf-8',
    (err, data) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      values = data.toString().split('\n');

      const listItems = values.map(val => <p>{val}</p>);
      return callback(listItems);
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: Tried this exact code, I now get an error that says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'result' of null`.

Comment: you need to initialize state in the constructor. I updated the answer.